# Android keep same progress bar between all activities

Tags: android, progress-bar, master-pages

My app has an async task queue that is being processed while user is doing something in the app.

I want to have a single progress bar showing the progress across all activities

How can I do it?

Is it possible to have on android something like a master page with the main layout and change only its center? keeping the progress bar at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Use fragments. Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments). You can have one fragment for your progress bar. And change the change the other.